# Как использовать библиотеку, скачанную с github?

Tags: java, github, library

первый раз пишу проект с использованием внешних библиотек, и не могу понять, как ее импортировать и использовать в своем проекте?

Допустим, я хочу использовать эту библиотеку: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/releases/

Comment: [If you use Maven, Gradle, etc; you should be able to import the dependency directly from Maven Central Repository.](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: @tym32167 Но когда я так делаю, то maven ругается и пишет Dependency 'org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0' not found

Comment: `maven install` пробовали?

Comment: @tym32167 все, сработало спасибо, мда, такой глупый вопрос, спасибо, что уделили мне свое время

Comment: на здоровье. Оформил ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для установки с помощью Maven вам понадобится:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
  <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Больше опций в [документации](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Getting-Started)